# Initialising a uint64_t with bitwise shifts greater than 31 result in zero being assigned

Tags: objective-c, integer, bit-shift, literals

if I declare a variable of type uint64_t and assign it the value 1 << 34 i.e. shift the value left by 34 bits the result variable is set to 0. Any shift > 31 gives 0 and shifts < 31 are work just fine.

My assignment statement is:

uint64_t test34B = (uint64_t)1 << 34;

Is there an Xcode compiler setting I'm missing or something?

Comment: How about `1ull << 34`?

Comment: Ah, found the problem! My code was:  uint64_t test34B = 1 << 34; but changed it to uint64_t test34B = (uint64_t)1 << 34; and warning is gone - forgot about the implicit type of the right hand operand!

Comment: The warning is only the beginning of the problem! The value after the assignment is zero! Shifts of upto 31 work correctly but >32 result in test34B being zero!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a 32-bit platform, the literal `1` will be 32-bit, and hence the compiler error.

Instead use a literal explicitly sized to 64-bits using the `ull` suffix:

```
uint64_t n = 1ull << 34;
```

Comment: Sorry trojanfoe - I've updated the question to a slightly different one as the warning was only the start of the problem - I've updated the original question with the real problem now.

Comment: trojanfoe's answer still solves your problem, @JayJay.

Comment: @JoshCaswell the casting of 1 doesn't result in the assignment of the correct value. As I state in the question any shift > 31 results in zero being assigned.

Comment: @JayJay My answer doesn't contain any casting.

Comment: Hi @trojanfoe sorry for my imprecise language. I've just tested your statement and n is assigned a value of 0 .

Comment: @JayJay I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain the same code as trojanfoe's answer, @JayJay. Although actually I think it should be equivalent.

Comment: @trojanfoe apologies, my test routine that printed out the value in binary had a bug in it, the correct value is being assigned thanks.